# How can you refresh SQL connection in excel without opening the excel sheet

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

I have a spreadsheet that need to be kept up-to-date by periodically refreshing the connection to the backend SQL database. Right now I have the excel speadsheet left open on my desktop 24x7 in order to keep the refresh active. Is there a  way I can refresh the external data connection in the Excel without opening the spreadsheet       ?

Comment: There's no way. You can write a shell script that can automate it for your, but technically it will just open the spreadsheet in background

Comment: Question: why do you need the spreadsheet to be updated if you don't look at it? Will the data be lost? Is another tool using the spreadsheet as data source? I any case I would ask if this is the right answer for whatever scenario ...

Answer (score 3):

To stop a refresh, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. To refresh a worksheet, press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. To refresh a workbook, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

To automatically refresh data at regular intervals:

1. Select a cell in the external data range.
2. Select `Data > Queries & Connections > Connections` tab, right click a query in the list, and then select `Properties`.
3. Click the `Usage` tab.
4. Select the `Refresh every` check box, and then enter the number of minutes between each refresh operation.

If your workbook is connected to a large data source, refreshing it might take a little longer than you expect. Consider running a background refresh. This returns control of Excel to you instead of making you wait several minutes or more for the refresh to finish.

Note: You can't run an OLAP query in the background and you can't run a query for any connection type that retrieves data for the Data Model.

1. Select a cell in the external data range.
2. Select `Data > Queries & Connections > Connections` tab, right click a query in the list, and then select `Properties`.
3. Select the `Usage` tab.
4. Select the `Enable background refresh` check box to run the query in the background. Clear this check box to run the query while you wait.

Tip    While you record a macro that includes a query, Excel doesn't run the query in the background. To change the recorded macro so that the query runs in the background, edit the macro in the Visual Basic Editor. Change the refresh method for the QueryTable object from BackgroundQuery := False to BackgroundQuery := True.